# Alter text contents of cells in PdfPTable object

Tags: text, itext, pdfptable

While parsing XML, I get a PdfPTable object. I want to modify text in some of its cells and write it in the end of each page (it should store sums of cells above), but I can't find out how to access particular cell and rewrite text in it? What is the way to do that?
The second way I guess is to copy every cell of a reference table except those to store sums, adding sums when needed, but that means copying all the properties, etc. It will be much better just to modify text in particular cells...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my fault, haven't read enough itext docs. For those who looks for the solution of the same problem: deep copying of a PdfPTable object with flushing its contents and filling it with cells again solved the problem.